# What statistical methods should i use to identify segments in a population according to a response variable?

Tags: regression, logistic, partitioning

Assuming I have $p$ uncorrelated explanatory variables $(X_i)_{i=1...p}$ and one binary response variable $Y$, such that : $$\log\left(\dfrac{P(Y=0|X)}{1-P(Y=0|X)}\right)=1_{\{X_1>0\}}\sum_{i=2}^p\alpha_iX_i + 1_{\{X_1\leq0\}}\sum_{i=2}^p\beta_iX_i$$
What statistical method should i use in order to detect the partitioning rule $X_1>0$ that is defined in my logistic regression based on the data $(X,Y)$?

Comment: Can you say more? What is the "partitioning rule x_1>0"? you've written a logistic model for x_i, i > 2, with breakpoints at 0 for all covariates.

Comment: What I mean is that the effect of the covariates x_i for i>2 on y depends on whether x_1>0 or not. I gave this logistic model as an example because I want to be able to identify this kind of rule on a dataset (x,y) and i'm looking for a statistical method in order to do so.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are asking for is a test of interaction. Interaction is most easily summarized as a product between two covariates (or some appropriate transformation thereof), treated as a third covariate in the model. The hypothesis of interaction (say between $X_1$ and $X_2$) is stated that: under the null, any expected difference in the outcome $Y$ comparing groups differing by one unit in $X_1$ remains the same irrespective of $X_2$.

The model you've written above indicates that there is a slope in each of the covariates $X_2$ which follows $\alpha$ when $X_1 < 0$ and $\beta$ when $X_1 > 0$. It leaves us at a bit of a loss how to write the null model, but a reasonable assumption might be:

$$ \mbox{logit} (y) = \sum_{i=2}^p \beta_i X_i$$

indicating there may be slopes in the other covariates but they do not differ with respect to $X_1$.

If we define a new covariate $Y_1 = \mathcal{I} (X_1 > 0)$, we can create derived variables and re-express your model in terms of

$$\mbox{logit} (Y) = \sum_{i=2}^p \alpha_i X_i + \sum_{i=2}^p \gamma_i X_i Y_1 $$

where $\gamma_i = \beta_i - \alpha_i$.

The statistical significance of the $\gamma_i$ fit with the logistic regression model indicates the presence of interaction as described.

Comment: You're right but I need to identify the interaction first before testing its statistical significance. Your solution works in case I already know that  $Y_1=1_{\{X_1>0\}}$ interacts with $X_i$ for $i>2$. I'm looking for a method to approximate the breakpoint on $X_1$.